# VScode Haskell debugger issue

Tags: haskell, vscode-debugger

I've been trying to install the Haskell debugger in VSCode and so far I've reached having both phoityne-vscode and Haskell-dap installed but when I try to run the debugger an error appears stating:

```
ghci launch error. <file descriptor: 5>: hPutChar: resource vanished (Broken Pipe)
```

The full terminal readout on VSCode also reads:

```
CMD: stack ghci --test --no-load --no-build --main-is TARGET --ghci-options -fprint-evld-with-show --with-ghc=haskell-dap 


Note: No local targets specified, so a plain ghci will be started with no package hiding or package
  options.

  You are using snapshot: lts-15.11

  If you want to use package hiding and options, then you can try one of the following:

  * If you want to start a different project configuration
    than C:\sr\global-project\stack.yaml, then you can use stack init to create a new stack.yaml
    for the packages in the current directory. 

  * If you want to use the project configuration
    at C:\sr\global-project\stack.yaml, then you can add to its 'packages' field.

Configuring GHCi with the following packages: 
Haskell-dap is deprecated.
```

I'm assuming that the "Haskell-dap is deprecated." message is the cause of the issue as running "Haskell-dap --version" in the Windows console gives me the same message, but I've been unable to find any suggested fixes online for this. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like it closed the stdin, when a program (likely `ghci`) expected more characters to be part passed to the stdin.

Comment: Apologies as I'm still new to using both Haskell and VSCode. What do you suggest would be the solution to the problem?

Comment: The solution may be to use hdx4vsc instead of phoityne-vscode as detailed in this github issue : https://github.com/phoityne/phoityne-vscode/issues/48 .   ( That's been working for me on linux )